# how to exit this function / class?

Tags: android, function, class, listview, dialog

Currently I am doing a testing on a app where I can trigger a function/class from the button onclicklistener. After that it will call out this function/class below:

```
 void beta(){

        final ListView XX= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        xx.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

               TextView A= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.A);
               TextView B= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.B);
               TextView C= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.C);
               String AA= ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.A)).getText().toString();
               String BB = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.B)).getText().toString();
               String CC= ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.C)).getText().toString();
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("StrikeThrought Selected Item?");
                adb.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Click button action
                         A.setPaintFlags(A.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                         B.setPaintFlags(B.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                         C.setPaintFlags(C.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                adb.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Click button action
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        return;
                    }
                });

                adb.setCancelable(false);
                adb.show();

              }
        });
     }
```

When I select a list item in the listview, a dialog box will pop up asking if I will like to strikethrough all the textview in the selected list item.

As of now it is working well but as of now I am unable to exit this function. Whenever I select another item in is listview. 
The intended function was to trigger once regardless if the user press yes or no and exit this function. 
Anyone can give me any advise where I am missing?

update 1:
just to make it clear. i want the beta() to be trigger once only and if user want to use this function again, the user will need to press the button to trigger this function/class again. The dialog part is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line which was not allowing you to exit the dialog.

```
adb.setCancelable(false);
```

Or make it to true.

This method call with false is required only when you want to take one of the actions.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have try to replace it to true and removing it. still the same. the app is stuck in the said function/class. anymore suggestion?